# Hibernate Search with index in a different database

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search, compass-lucene

I have a database which is readonly (I only have the access to view), but I have to index this database for search. The DAO layer to this table is now using a generic DAO approach with Hibernate+JPA. Is it possible to add hibernate search to this view and store the index in a separate database?

I am aware that I may lose the capability of post- indexing. But it is ok, I will do full indexing manually.

Configuration: Spring 2.5+Hibernate 3

(Or should I use compass or lucene directly?)

Please Advise
Thanks
Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Search and Compass both use Lucene under the covers, and Lucene can store its index data in various forms, including in memory, on disk, or in a database. If you choose to store it in a database, then there's no reason that needs to be the same database as the data you're indexing.

However, if there's no concrete need to keep the index in a database, then local disk-based storage will be easier, and probably faster.

Comment: Is it feasible to use database store option for multiple nodes to use same index to avoid complex cluster configuration ?